# Formatting an array being printed in the shell using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, command-line

so I have a bash script that is supposed to print peoples names and their scores from a text file

The text input file is as follows

```
Ted 86 
Anthony 70
Mark 95
Kyle 65
David 75
```

This is my code

```
#! /bin/bash
inputfile="$1"

 if [[ !(-f "$1") ]]; then
    echo "$1 must be a file"
    exit 1
 else
    echo "$1 is a file"
 fi
                                                                                                                    
 names=()                                                                                                                
 scores=()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 while read line                                                                                                         
 do                                                                                                                              
   lineArray=($line)                                                                                                       
   names+=(${lineArray[0]})
   scores+=(${lineArray[1]})                                                                                       
 done < $inputfile
                                                                                                                    
 echo "${names[@]} ${scores[@]}"
```

This is the output

```
score is a file
Ted Anthony Mark Kyle David 86 70 95 65 75
```

My issue is, I need the output to be displayed in the same way as it appears in the input text file and I don't know how to use a loop to do it. Thank you

Comment: Isn't it obvious that you should use a loop?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a `for` loop to loop over the entries in the two arrays.

```
#!/bin/bash

inputfile="$1"

if [[ ! -f $inputfile ]]; then
    echo "$inputfile must be a file"
    exit 1
else
    echo "$inputfile is a file"
fi

names=()
scores=()

while IFS= read -r name score
do
    names+=( "$name" )
    scores+=( "$score" )
done < $inputfile

# like this:

for ((i=0; i<${#names[@]}; ++i))
do
    echo "${names[$i]} ${scores[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: Consider quoting, as in `names+=( "$name" )`. If someone names themselves `*`, we don't want to add a list of filenames in the current directory to the array.